# How to set Menubutton always on top of other component like HBox (which is draggable)

Tags: javafx

I have a parent VBox which holds a menu button and a draggable HBox. When I drag the HBox, the menu button is not responding (because the HBox is set over the menu button). How do I always set the menu button on top of the HBox if it is draggable?

HBoxandVBoxExampleupdated.java:

```
import DraggableNode;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;

import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStroke;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStrokeStyle;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderWidths;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HBoxandVBoxExampleupdated extends Application
{
    static Pane             pane    = new Pane();
    static DraggableNode    node    = new DraggableNode();
    static NumberAxis       noaxis  = new NumberAxis();
    static String           ref     = "HHHHHelllelelelellelellelelellelelelaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

    static HBox             nobox   = new HBox();
    static NumberAxis       lineXAxis;
    static String           Style   = "-fx-border-color: blue;\n"
                                            + "-fx-border-insets: 5;\n"
                                            + "-fx-border-width: 3;\n"
                                            + "-fx-border-style: dashed;\n";
    static String           Style1  = "-fx-border-color: red;\n"
                                            + "-fx-border-insets: 5;\n"
                                            + "-fx-border-width: 3;\n"
                                            + "-fx-border-style: dashed;\n";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        pane.setStyle(Style);
        node.setStyle(Style1);
        VBox mainbox = new VBox(80);
        mainbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        mainbox.setPadding(new Insets(50, 30, 100, 50));

        VBox hbox = new VBox(60);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); // default TOP_LEFT
        HBox vbox1 = new HBox();
        HBox vbox2 = new HBox(10);
        HBox vbox3 = new HBox(20);

        Button close = new Button("X");
        Button close1 = new Button("X");
        MenuButton vcfmenu = new MenuButton("Vcf");

        vcfmenu.getItems().add(new CheckMenuItem("About This Track"));
        vcfmenu.getItems().add(new CheckMenuItem("Ping To Tap"));
        vcfmenu.getItems().add(new CheckMenuItem("Edit Config"));
        vcfmenu.getItems().add(new CheckMenuItem("Delete Track"));
        vcfmenu.getItems().add(new CheckMenuItem("Save Track Data"));
        vcfmenu.getItems().add(new CheckMenuItem("Show Labels"));
        vcfmenu.getItems().add(new CheckMenuItem("Hides Sites Passing All Filters"));
        vcfmenu.getItems().add(new CheckMenuItem("Hides Sites not Passing All Filters"));

        vbox2.getChildren().add(vcfmenu);

        for (String s : ref.split("")) {
            Label l = new Label(s);
            l.setBorder(new Border(
                    new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT)));
            l.setBackground(
                    new Background(
                            new BackgroundFill(
                                    (s.equals("N") ? Color.web("#DDDDDD")
                                            : (s.equals("A") ? Color.web("#00BF00")
                                                    : (s.equals("C") ? Color.web("#0099FF")
                                                            : (s.equals("T") ? Color.web("#F00")
                                                                    : Color.web("#D5BB04"))))),
                                    CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
            l.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            l.setPadding(new Insets(1, 4, 1, 4));

            vbox1.getChildren().add(l);

        }

        lineXAxis = new NumberAxis(1, ref.length(), 4);

        nobox.getChildren().add(lineXAxis);
        nobox.setHgrow(lineXAxis, Priority.ALWAYS);

        mainbox.getChildren().addAll(vbox2);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(nobox, vbox1);

        node.getChildren().add(hbox);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(node, mainbox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1150, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("HBox and VBox Example");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

DraggableNode.java:

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class DraggableNode extends StackPane {

    private double  x           = 0;
    private double  y           = 0;

    private double  mousex      = 0;
    private double  mousey      = 0;
    private Node    view;
    private boolean dragging    = false;
    private boolean moveToFront = true;
    private double  size        = 0;
    private double  newSize     = 0;

    public DraggableNode() {
        init();
    }

    public DraggableNode(Node view) {
        this.view = view;

        getChildren().add(view);
        setMouseTransparent(true);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        onMousePressedProperty().set(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);

                // record the current mouse X and Y position on Node
                mousex = event.getSceneX();
                mousey = event.getSceneY();

                x = getLayoutX();
                y = getLayoutY();

                if (isMoveToFront()) {
                    toFront();
                }
            }
        });

        onMouseDraggedProperty().set(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                double offsetX = event.getSceneX() - mousex;

                x += offsetX;

                double scaledX = x;
                System.out.println(" : " + scaledX);
                if (scaledX > 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                setLayoutX(scaledX);

                dragging = false;
                mousex = event.getSceneX();

                event.consume();
            }
        });

        onMouseClickedProperty().set(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                dragging = false;
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * @return the dragging
     */
    protected boolean isDragging() {
        return dragging;
    }

    /**
     * @return the view
     */
    public Node getView() {
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * @param moveToFront
     *            the moveToFront to set
     */
    public void setMoveToFront(boolean moveToFront) {
        this.moveToFront = moveToFront;
    }

    /**
     * @return the moveToFront
     */
    public boolean isMoveToFront() {
        return moveToFront;
    }

    public void removeNode(Node n) {
        getChildren().remove(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to stack the `MenuButton` on top of the `HBox`? Or, do you just want to arrange the two nodes just adjacent to each other?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha : hi ...actually when i dragged HBox my  hbox container activate and when i dragged it it comes over the menu button because of that my menu button is not responding so i want to respond it . if hbox goes on over of it....

Comment: @ItachiUchiha : check the code ...:)

Comment: If a node is draggable and you place it on top of another node, then the latter cannot receive any user inputs. If you want the HBox to not block the mouse events. You can set [mouseTransparentProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#mouseTransparentProperty) as true.

Comment: But, I do not find a StackPane in your code. How does the HBox places itself on top of the menu button?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha : where to use stackPane actually drag component extend pane if i change it to stack pane it . no change....

Comment: I am posting that code also..

Comment: I am talking about the container, not the draggable node.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha : if it uses parent container as stackpane .it didn;t responding not button and not drag.....

Comment: Your code has too many dependencies and I cannot test it. Can you please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha : i  am Edit it Check Now...

Comment: The problem, as already identified, is with the method `toFront()`. The best way is using `onMouseReleasedProperty()` to again send it to back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the DraggableNode to the front in the EventHandler for `onMousePressedProperty`. This puts DraggableNode on top of its sibling nodes and prevents the menu button from receiving mouse inputs.

To prevent this, I see two options:

1. don't set the DraggableNode to the front by setting `moveToFront = false` or, if that isn't possible,
2. set the DraggableNode to the back again after dragging by adding

   ```
   onMouseReleasedProperty().set(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
       @Override
       public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
           toBack();
       }
   });
   ```

   to the init method of DraggableNode.

---

For a more general solution, you could add a property to DraggableNode

```
private BooleanProperty dragInProcessProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
public BooleanProperty dragInProcessProperty() {
    return this.dragInProcessProperty;
}
```

Set the property to `true` while dragging in onMouseDraggedProperty and to `false` when the mouse is released

```
onMouseReleasedProperty().set(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        dragInProcessProperty.set(false);
    }
});
```

and add a ChangeListener to the dragInProgressProperty in HBoxandVBoxExampleupdated

```
node.dragInProcessProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        if (!newValue.booleanValue()) {
            mainbox.toFront();
        }
    }
});
```

to set the node to the front whenever dragging is finished.